# Widgets in Footer Won't Align Properly

Tags: css, wordpress, widget, alignment, footer

I've tried searching for this and can't seem to find my specific problem or a solution.

In the footer widget area of the website I'm working on, I can't get them to align horizontally.

Here's my test site, I'm not even sure what code to share here.
http://test.likeabirdblog.com

In the widgets, I want the top of the "next release" and the search bar to be in line with the newsletter widget in the middle. I have text-align:center in the code which is what I've found as the most common suggestion but it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your css:

```
#footerwidget .widget-area { vertical-align : top ; }
```

That will make all three `.widget-area`s stick to the top of the footer bar.

There's an extra paragraph in the middle widget, at the top, above the blue box, which makes the blue box appear lower...get rid of that paragraph element, and then add padding to the top of `#footerwidget`.

```
#footerwidget { padding-top : 20px ; }
```

Then, the tops of all three boxes will line up.

Comment: Doesn't adding padding make it less mobile responsive? I've been trying to avoid using padding.

Comment: No, it doesn't. But you can remove the padding, and my answer still stands...vertical-align and getting rid of extraneous paragraphs is the simplest way to solve your question. If you're worried about responsiveness, you should create a media query so that the padding is whatever you want on the desktop, and then something different in mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this CSS:

```
#footerwidget {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: flex-start;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
#footmiddle > ul > li > div > p {
    display: none;
}
#footright > div > form {
    margin-top: 2px;
}
#footleft {
    margin-top: -3px;
}
#footmiddle .newsletter-cont {
    max-height: 176px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a bunch of unnecessary CSS that makes it harder to make style consistent. Here's what you should remove (`-`) and add (`+`):

```
#footleft {
- max-width: 400px;
- width: 100%;
- height: auto;
- display: inline-block;
- text-align: center;
}
#footmiddle {
- max-width: 400px;
- width: 100%;
- height: auto;
- display: inline-block;
- text-align: center;
}
#footright {
- max-width: 400px;
- width: 100%;
- height: auto;
- display: inline-block;
- text-align: center;
}
#footerwidget {
- height: auto;
- width: 100%;
- float: left;
- overflow: hidden;
- background-color: #a1025f;
+ display: flex;
+ max-width: 1100px; // or whatever you need
}
.newsletter-cont {
- margin: 2px;
}
.form-wrapper-2 {
- margin: 25px auto;
+ margin: 0 auto;
}
2c-r.css
#footer {
+ background-color: #a1025f;
```

You'll also want to remove a couple of empty `<p>` tags in there that add blank space on top of forms

Comment: That kind of worked but everything is pushed to the left and no spaces between each widget space.

Comment: I don't know how you want your layout to exactly look like. If you want more spacing between widgets, just add margin.
If it's not centered, post a link to your new code, something else is wrong.